# 'libpng error: Invalid IHDR data' and cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, raspberry-pi3, opencv

I'm trying to use face recognition with Raspberry pi3 and pi camera.
The working environment is as follows.

```
Python 2.7.13
Python3 3.5.3
scikit-learn 0.18
numpy 1.12.1
scipy 0.18.1
matplotlib 2.0.0
PIL(Pillow) 4.0.0
keras 2.2.0
theano 1.0.2
```

When I execute the program, the following error appears.
Searching the errors on stackoverflow and other sites, there was one solution to use 'VideoCapture(1)' instead of 'VideoCapture(0)', but in my case, it doesn't work.
 Then, when I search the error about 'libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR', there was a proposal to insert time.sleep() to wait for camera startup. I tried it, but it did not work for me.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/20180717_WebScrb $ python3 face_detection.py
Using Theano backend.
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 331
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_detection.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "face_detection.py", line 63, in main
    cv2.imshow("Show FLAME Image", frame)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Python code is as below.

```
import face_keras as face
import sys, os
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


cascade_path = "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
#cascade_path = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
color = (255, 255, 255)

image_size = 32
categories = ["obama", "trump"]

def main():
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        facerect = cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=2, minSize=(10, 10))
        cv2.imwrite("frontalface.png", frame)
        img = cv2.imread("frontalface.png")
        for rect in facerect:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, tuple(rect[0:2]),tuple(rect[0:2] + rect[2:4]), color, thickness=2)
            x = rect[0]
            y = rect[1]
            width = rect[2]
            height = rect[3]
            dst = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
            cv2.imwrite("output.png", dst)
            cv2.imread("output.png")
            X = []

            img = load_img("./output.png", target_size=(image_size,image_size))
            in_data = img_to_array(img)

            X.append(in_data)
            X = np.array(X)
            X  = X.astype("float")  / 256

            model = face.build_model(X.shape[1:])
            model.load_weights("./image/face-model.h5")

            pre = model.predict(X)
            print(pre)
            if pre[0][0] > 0.9:
                print(categories[0])
                text = categories[0] + str(pre[0][0]*100) + "%"
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
                cv2.putText(frame,text,(rect[0],rect[1]-10),font, 2, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            elif pre[0][1] > 0.9:
                print(categories[1])
                text = categories[1] + str(pre[0][1]*100) + "%"
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
                cv2.putText(frame,text,(rect[0],rect[1]-10),font, 2, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            elif pre[0][2] > 0.9:
                print(categories[2])
                text = categories[2] + str(pre[0][2]*100) + "%"
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
                cv2.putText(frame,text,(rect[0],rect[1]-10),font, 2, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow("Show FLAME Image", frame)
        time.sleep(0.4)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if k == ord('q'):
            break

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think   'cv2.imwrite("frontalface.png", frame)'   is not working because it outputs frontalface.png in a current folder, but it's 0 byte (empty).
I'm sorry if this post is exactly the same content as someone's question. However, I could not find it by myself trying. So let me ask you a question here.

Comment: How can your working environment include Python 2.7.13 *and* Python 3.5.3?

Comment: sorry I mistyped
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
    Python 2.7.13
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 --version
    Python 3.5.3

Comment: The idea behind my comment is that you work *either* in Python 2.7.13 *or* in Python 3.5.3. Listing all the Python versions available in your machine is meaningless for the question

Answer (score 1):

try to test if  dst[0] is not equal to 0. Please check this correction and tell me if it works.

```
  dst = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
  if dst[0].size > 0:
         cv2.imwrite("output.png", dst)
```